# Protein Powder certified kosher but no hescher on package

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization, dairy

A family member bought protein powder which I believed was under OU supervision. It is 100% vegan and has no dairy derivatives which I know means nothing in the kosher world but still. It is missing a hescher on it, the product is advertised as kosher and OU is very proud to sell it under the OU label. So these are my questions, 1. Is it fit for use. If Chos Vsholom the answer is no then 2. Do I need to kasher my dishes, it was placed in yogurt which was cleaned within 24 hours. Mods please don't take another one of my posts down, the reason I let the family member use the powder was it costed $33 and I did not think much of it till now.

Comment: Hi Mosh. It sounds like you'd have much better luck contacting the OU directly about your particular product https://oukosher.org/contact-us/